# Invoke custom Maven plugin before the compiler plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I wrote a plugin which should execute at compile phase. It generates some source code which is being used by other Java classes.

When I normally add this plugin in my POM, I face a compilation error because Maven first execute the compiler plugin and then my plugin. So while compiling, it fails because it need the source code which is generated by my own plugin.

How do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The fix is to invoke your plugin before the compilation of the sources. Compilation, as done by [`maven-compiler-plugin:compile`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html), happens by default in the `compile` phase of the [default lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).

Before that `compile` phase, the default lifecycle also invokes the `generate-sources`, [which purpose is](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) to:

> generate any source code for inclusion in compilation.

Therefore, you should bind your plugin to the phase `generate-sources` instead of the `compile` phase. This can either be done using the `defaultPhase` attribute of your MOJO with

```java
@Mojo(name = "example", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.GENERATE_SOURCES)
```

or declaring it explicitely in the POM in its executions:

```
<execution>
    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
    <!-- id, goal and configuration -->
</execution>
```

---

You'll need to make sure the classes you generated in that phase are correctly added to the buildpath. If the plugin doesn't do it already (by calling [`MavenProject.addCompileSourceRoot(directory)`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html#addCompileSourceRoot%28java.lang.String%29)), you can make use of the [`build-helper-maven-plugin:add-source`](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/add-source-mojo.html) goal to add the directory where the sources have been generated to the buildpath.